# How to add a token to Phantom Wallet?

Tags: wallet, token

I recently installed the wallet, but there are no tokens that I am interested in, I watched a tutorial on youtube how to add a token through "manage token list" but there is no "+" button can you help with this? The version of the wallet is the latest[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Phantom, the process of adding tokens is slightly different from what you might have seen in some tutorials or videos.

Unlike traditional wallets where you manually add tokens using a "+" button, Phantom Wallet automatically displays tokens once they are associated with your wallet address. This can happen in two ways:

**Receiving Tokens:**

If someone sends you tokens to your Phantom wallet address, those tokens will automatically appear in your wallet once the transaction is confirmed on the Solana blockchain.

**Creating Custom Tokens yourself:**

You can also create your own custom tokens using the Solana Command Line Interface (CLI). This involves creating a token mint and associated accounts on the Solana blockchain. Once created, these custom tokens will be visible in your Phantom Wallet.

Answer (score 0):

usually the tokens just show up once you have them in your wallet

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/4696)